# Android sendBroadcast to other module

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-module

I have a main application module "app1" and a second module "app2" that starts as "process:SecondActivity". I need to send a message from SecondActivity using a broadcast receiver, but the message does not come in onRecive. Broadcast receiver is in module "tools", 
Modules "app1" and "app2" dependent on the module "tools".

My broadcast receiver

```
class ExportReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

companion object {

    const val ACTION_EXPORT = "ACTION_EXPORT"

    @JvmStatic
    fun getIntentFilters() = IntentFilter(ACTION_EXPORT)

}

@FunctionalInterface
interface OnExport {
    fun onExport(uri: Uri)
}

private var mExport : OnExport? = null

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    intent?.let {
        if (it.action == ACTION_EXPORT) {
            it.data?.let { uri ->
                mExport?.onExport(uri)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun setExport(export: OnExport) {
    mExport = export
}
}
```

Register receiver to "app1"

```
mExportReceiver = new ExportReceiver();
mExportReceiver.setExport(uri -> {});
mContext.registerReceiver(mExportReceiver, ExportReceiver.getIntentFilters());
```

Send broadcast to "app2"

```
override fun onExportFile(fileUri: Uri?) {
    fileUri?.let {
        sendBroadcast(Intent(ExportReceiver.ACTION_EXPORT).apply {
            data = fileUri
        })
    }
}
```